# MSSQLSERVER Stuck in 'Starting'

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I'm running a Sharepoint installation over 3 VMs and my SQLVM can no longer start the MSSQLSERVER service. It gets stuck at 'Starting' and uses 100% of a processor core but seems to do nothing. The error log is as follows:

```
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) 
    Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      UTC adjustment: 1:00
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      All rights reserved.
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      Server process ID is 4660.
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Microsoft Corporation', System Model: 'Virtual Machine'.
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'E:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      The service account is 'LUNET\elsqlservice-svc'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d E:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e E:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l E:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2017-04-12 11:28:50.86 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "MSSQLSERVER"
2017-04-12 11:28:51.33 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.33 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.33 Server      Detected 32765 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.33 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.47 Server      Default collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2017-04-12 11:28:51.53 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2017-04-12 11:28:51.53 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 1612 at 12/04/2017 10:39:20 (local) 12/04/2017 09:39:20 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.53 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.59 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.63 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.64 spid7s      1 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.64 spid7s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.65 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.74 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.74 Server      Software Usage Metrics is enabled.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.77 spid7s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2017-04-12 11:28:51.77 spid7s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After falling through the rabbit hole trying to solve this issue I highly recommend running `Windows Sysinternals Process Monitor` for anyone with a similar issue. This highlighted repeated access to a corrupt file that was the source of the problem.